Why does this seemingly innocuous range-v3 code crash?
I have some usage of Range-v3 roughly like so:
std::vector<Foo> vec = co_await scanFoo();
auto toProcess = vec
  | views::filter([&](auto&& e){ return myPredicate(e); })
  | views::transform([](auto&& e) { return std::move(e); })
  | ranges::to_vector

The same logic written iteratively does not reproduce a crash:
for (auto&& e : vec) {
  if (myPredicate(e)) {
    toProcess.push_back(std::move(e));
  }
}

Some details about the crash:

ASAN heap-buffer overflow
It occurs in the move constructor of Foo, as executed within ranges::to_vector
This crash does not reproduce readily; it requires running continuously for vectors of sizes 0-10000+ for sometimes up to an hour to reproduce
Presumably, the same element is being moved-from twice. I don't see how that is possible, but it seems the only explanation here
Is it possibly related to Why C++ ranges "transform -> filter" calls transform twice for values that match the filter's predicate?

Further questions:

I now realize this is not the correct way to move elements, and to use ranges::views::move instead. However, is that safe here? What other footguns lurk with move? What are the best practices around it?


transforming a filter is UB IIRC

Should be views::transform([](auto&& e) -> auto&& { return std::move(e); }).
